# RelayCommand commandParameter is null

Tags: wpf, vb.net, null, relaycommand, commandparameter

I have a button on my usercontrol

```
<Button Grid.Row="13" Grid.Column="7" Content="Save" Name="btnSave" 
            CommandParameter="{Binding CompanyDetails}"
            Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
```

SaveCommand is a RelayCommand declared in the ViewModel.
CompanyDetails is a property in the same ViewModel.
The mentioned above ViewModel is the datacontext of my UserControl.

```
    Public Class CompanyViewModel
    Inherits ViewModelBase
    Implements IDataErrorInfo

    Private _myData As DataFromDatabase      
    Private _companyDetails As New CompanyDetailsBase
    Private _saveCommand As RelayCommandWithParameter

    Public Property CompanyDetails() As CompanyDetailsBase
        Get
            Return _companyDetails
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As CompanyDetailsBase)
            _companyDetails = value
            OnPropertyChanged("CompanyDetails")
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property SaveCommand() As RelayCommandWithParameter
        Get
            If _saveCommand Is Nothing Then
                Dim saveAction As New Action(Of Object)(AddressOf Me.SaveIt)
                _saveCommand = New RelayCommandWithParameter(saveAction) ', Me.CanSave)
            End If
            Return _saveCommand
        End Get

        Set(ByVal value As RelayCommandWithParameter)
            _saveCommand = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        _myData = New DataFromDatabase(My.Settings.ConnectionString)
        _saveCommand = New RelayCommandWithParameter(New Action(Of Object)(AddressOf SaveIt))
    End Sub

    Public Function GetCompanyDetails(ByVal sap As String) As CompanyDetailsBase
        CompanyDetails = _myData.GetCompanyDetails(sap)
        Return CompanyDetails
    End Function

    Public Sub SaveIt(ByVal c As CompanyDetailsBase)
        MessageBox.Show("Save customer " & c.Sap)
    End Sub

    End Class
```

The other fields on the usercontrol are bound to an ObjectDataProvider, which calls the GetCompanyDetails function. The CompanyDetails is set right each time this function is called, until I call SaveIt subroutine. When SaveIt is called its parameter is always Nothing. Where do I make the mistake?
Thank you a lot for answers.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructer of *CompanyViewModel* populate the *CompanyDetails* with your *GetCompanyDetails*  function. Change the constructor as bellow,

```
Public Sub New()
    _myData = New DataFromDatabase(My.Settings.ConnectionString)
    _saveCommand = New RelayCommandWithParameter(New Action(Of Object)(AddressOf SaveIt))
    _companyDetails = GetCompanyDetails()  
End Sub
```

This might help.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I did VB, and I never did it with WPF, but I think I know what your problem is.

The way you are initializing the Command, you aren't actually passing the parameter in.

When I do it in c# it looks like this =>

```
_saveCommand = new RelayCommandWithParameter(
            (param) =>
            {
                SaveIt((int)param);
            },
               // this line is the same as your commented out Me.CanSave
            (param) => { return this.CanDisplaySelectedPolicy; });
```

So you can see that in the lamda expression I pass a parameter called param, that is then put into the SaveIt method.

When you create your new action, try putting a lamda expression in it like the one above, so you can pass a parameter into the SaveIt method.